# Updating State from array

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React and I'm trying to update the state/ Router information of child component using onClick.

I'm able to acccess the state but cannot figure out how to iterate through the array and get the next object in the array onClick.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

The site and code examples are below:
https://tfelic3.github.io/bidencabinet/#/

```js
candidates: [
    {
        title: 'President',
        name: 'Joe Biden',
        description: 'The President is both the head of state and head of government of the United States of America, and Commander-in-Chief of the armed forces.',
        imgPath: 'img/biden4x4.png',
        nextPath: 'Vice President',
        id: 0
    }
]
```

Comment: It looks like ultimately the next button would need to be aware of the larger `candidates` array, and locate its current position via finding the index of the object with an `id` that matches itself, then find the next index candidate `candidates[self + 1]` to get the data needed to load the next candidate. You should show more code (missing a link? that is a published site with minified JS) or refine the question as this is missing too many pieces.